# Invoke private method using Apache MethodUtils

Tags: unit-testing, methods, private-methods

I am trying to invoke a private method in my unit test to initialize a value. I know I can use java reflections to invoke private methods, but I am wondering if I can use Apache MethodUtils to invoke a private method:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Private methods can be invoked using forceAccess = true:

```
MethodUtils.invokeMethod(ObjectName, true, "MethodName");
```